# Using AnyApi with React

Tags: java, reactjs, api

I am trying to use AnyApi with my react app.

The request parameters are
IMDBid:string  required
IMDB ID of the movie to return

GET [https://hydramovies.com/api-v2/%3Fsource=http:/hydramovies.com/api-v2/current-Movie-Data.csv&imdb_id={IMDBid}](https://hydramovies.com/api-v2/%3Fsource=http:/hydramovies.com/api-v2/current-Movie-Data.csv&imdb_id=%7BIMDBid%7D)

I want to be able to type in the input box and return searches from the api in my container.
Im not getting any response from the Api, can anyone help

```
// importing useState so we can create states 
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
// Imports style sheet for APP
import './App.css'; 

function App() {

  // setting imdbID so we can use this as a value in the input box
  const [imdbID,setimdbIDs] = useState('')

  const [container,setContainer] = useState([])
  useEffect(() =>{
    fetchMe()
  },[imdbID])

  const fetchMe = () => {

  fetch(`https://hydramovies.com/api-v2/%3Fsource=http:/hydramovies.com/api-v2/current-Movie-Data.csv&imdb_id={IMDBid}`, {
    "method": "GET"
})
.then(response => {
    return response.json();
})
.then(data => {
  setContainer(data.d)
})
.catch(err => {
    console.error(err);
});
  }

//Every letter that is typed in the input box will then change imdbID to setimdbIDs
const onChangeHandler = (e) => {
  setimdbIDs(e.target.value)
}

const submitHandler = e => {
  e.preventDefault()
}


  return (
    <div className="App"> 

      <form onSubmit={submitHandler}>

        {/* input box value is imdbID calling onChangeHandler state*/}
        <input type="text" value={imdbID} onChange={onChangeHandler}/>  
        {/* submit button */}
        <button type="submite">SUBMIT</button>

      </form>

      {container.map((item) =>{
        return (
          <p>{item.l}</p>
        )
      })}
      
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

You didnt provide the **IMDBid**  in the url correctly

the template literal should be given like `` `string${expression}` ``

so your code would be
`https://hydramovies.com/api-v2/%3Fsource=http:/hydramovies.com/api-v2/current-Movie-Data.csv&imdb_id=${IMDBid}`

Comment: thank you i missed that! but its saying fail to fetch

Comment: that might be problem with the server try some other APIs